# Null PointerException in spinner in android

Tags: java, android

I am working in Android. I want to design a spinner of song categories.

This is my code:

```
public Spinner spinner_category_forSong;

String[] arr_Category={"Select","sad","dj","rock"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arr_Category);

spinner_category_forSong = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner_category_forUpload);    
spinner_category_forSong.setPrompt("Music Category :");
spinner_category_forSong.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But whenever I run my project, a null pointer exception is created in       `spinner_category_forSong.setPrompt("Music Category :");` and `spinner_category_forSong.setAdapter(adapter);`.

Please tell me what mistake I have made in this code.

Comment: Please show the logcat output...

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pericent/com.pericent.FileUploadWithChooser}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.pericent.FileUploadWithChooser.initSpinner_category(FileUploadWithChooser.java:157)
    at com.pericent.FileUploadWithChooser.onCreate(FileUploadWithChooser.java:40)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

Comment: well you can post the logcat in the question itself so that it is in a readable format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your exception it seems that `findViewById(R.id.Spinner_category_forUpload)` returns null. My guess is that you didn't call `setContentView()` prior to your method calls.

From the code sample your class structure is not clear. Are some lines inside `onCreate()`?

Comment: Hey Alex you are genius. your guess is right. i write setContentView(R.Layout.main) after above code. so this error is occured. Now this is resolved just because of you thank you so much... thank you all...

Answer (score 1):

try after setting adapter `spinner_category_forSong.setAdapter(adapter);` before `spinner_category_forSong.setPrompt("Music Category :");`

Comment: sorry vineet sir, that was not cause of my mistake. you helped me... thank you so much...